# Ruby - no such file to load [gems]

Tags: ruby, gem

This is error:

[ERROR] no such file to load -- readline
[TIP] Try to run 'gem install readline' or 'gem install --user-install readline'. If you still get an error, Please see README file or https://github.com/wpscanteam/wpscan

Then i run those command but again i got error:

ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'readline' (>= 0) in any repository

those errors i got when i use "ruby wpscan.rb" help me please.

Answer (score 1):

After command:

```
sudo gem install rb-readline
```

I was still getting an error.

I added to the Gemfile

```
gem "rb-readline"
```

And it worked.

Answer (score 0):

The [readline](https://rubygems.org/gems/rb-readline) library for Ruby is called `rb-readline`. Try

```
sudo gem install rb-readline
```

for a system-wide installation, or

```
gem install --user-install rb-readline
```

for a local installation inside your user's home directory.